# WPF / XAML / MVVM - Set state of checkboxes based on conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am a traditional MVC programmer that just started using MVVM and I do not know how I would program the below scenario the MVVM-way. I probably need multi binding, but can someone please help me and write that code for me? I've spend hours trying to achieve this, but I just don't know how to do it...

Btw, I know how to set the values from my settings file in XAML, but don't know how to write the other logic, EG:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=Pref_QuickProcess}"
```

**This is my scenario:**

I have a simple preferences screen with two checkboxes:

□ Quick process (value is set from Settings.Default.Pref_QuickProcess)

□ Upload to youtube (value is set from Settings.Default.Pref_UploadToYoutube)

The following conditions apply:

- If "Quick process" is true, "Upload to youtube" should always be set to false and must be disabled.
- If "Quick process" is false, "Upload to youtube" should be enabled.

These are the only options:

[image: Examples]

This is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SchismRecorder.PreferencesWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Preferences" Height="450" Width="800">

<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Debug settings" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="326" Margin="21,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="733">
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Content="Quick process" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="chkQuickProcess" />
            <CheckBox Content="Upload to Youtube" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="chkUploadToYoutube" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

This is my code behind:

```cs
public partial class PreferencesWindow : Window
{
    public PreferencesWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        chkQuickProcess.IsChecked = Settings.Default.Pref_QuickProcess;
        chkUploadToYoutube.IsChecked = Settings.Default.Pref_UploadToYoutube;

        ConfigureCheckboxes();

        chkQuickProcess.Click -= ChkQuickProcess_Click;
        chkQuickProcess.Click += ChkQuickProcess_Click;
    }

    private void ChkQuickProcess_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConfigureCheckboxes();
    }

    void ConfigureCheckboxes()
    {
        if (chkQuickProcess.IsChecked.HasValue)
        {
            var isChecked = chkQuickProcess.IsChecked.Value;

            if (isChecked)
            {
                chkUploadToYoutube.IsChecked = false;
                chkUploadToYoutube.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                chkUploadToYoutube.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.Pref_QuickProcess = chkQuickProcess.IsChecked ?? false;
        Settings.Default.Pref_UploadToYoutube = chkUploadToYoutube.IsChecked ?? false;
        Settings.Default.Save();

        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
}
```

**How do I get rid of my code behind, and get the same result in XAML with  things like data triggers, converters, multi binding?**

Edit: I think I do not necessarily need a viewmodel with setters to implement this logic, and do it with data triggers ? / multi binding ? instead. But maybe that is not possible?

Comment: Create a view model that represent the (functional) state of a view (i.e. a part of the UI). In your case, the state would encompass two boolean properties for "Quick Process" and "Upload to YT". Let the checkboxes bind to those properties. In the setters of those properties, implement the necessary code (or implement and call a method) that changes the value of other dependent properties according to the logic you want to employ (with that i mean the logic you have currently implemented within the PreferencesWindow class)

Comment: Thank you. I know how to code a view model, but in this case I think I don't need a view model. The values can be bound directly in XAML to static Settings.Settings, and I think it should be possible to control the logic using multi binding or data triggers, but I do not know how I should write that. However, maybe this is simply not possible? Otherwise, I'll try to implement the logic as you suggested, using setters

Comment: Okay, well you mentioned at the beginning of your question that you wanted it to do the MVVM-way. If you don't want to do it the MVVM-way, perhaps eliminate mentions of MVVM and the MVVM tag from your question...

Comment: You are right, I guess those things are not part of the viewmodel, I still get a bit confused with all the "new" stuff

Comment: That said, i guess it would and should be possible to do in XAML (perhaps in conjunction with some clever ValueConverter), but since i don't have an IDE at hand, i can't really mess around with XAML at the moment and thus can'make suggestions. However, i think that this would be much more messy and painful than employing a viewmodel. A viewmodel allows you to cleanly implement (and debug) your interaction logic without writing walls of XAML-text that is hard to debug and uni-test...

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for, something like a clever ValueConverter :) Thanks for the suggestions thus far, too bad you don't have an IDE at hand. And ok... I'd simply like to know if it's possible without a viewmodel and how to do it, to learn... But I guess you are right, that it's way easier to use a viewmodel instead.

Comment: The view is for presentation and the viewmodel is for business logic and data. You can code what you want, but don't call it MVVM if you don't follow it's rules. You want to put busines logic into the view and violate the pattern rules

Comment: Check the sample project https://github.com/SirRufo/so/blob/master/53016687/WpfApp1/WpfApp1/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need a view model just to set a few properties in the Settings class that have a certain interdependence. The following XAML should do most or perhaps all of what you are describing.

When the first Checkbox is checked, the `IsChecked` and `IsEnabled` properties of the second Checkbox are set to false. However, the `Settings.Default.Pref_UploadToYoutube` property value is not changed. Not sure if this is strictly required.

By default, the second CheckBox's `IsChecked` property is bound to `Pref_UploadToYoutube` via a Style Setter. A DataTrigger on the `Pref_QuickProcess` property replaces the Binding and sets `IsChecked` and `IsEnabled` to false.

Also note the new Binding Path syntax for binding to static properties.

```
<CheckBox Content="Quick process"
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=(p:Settings.Default).Pref_QuickProcess}"/>

<CheckBox Content="Upload to Youtube">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked"
                    Value="{Binding Path=(p:Settings.Default).Pref_UploadToYoutube}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(p:Settings.Default).Pref_QuickProcess}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

You may also simplify the Settings properties binding paths by assigning the `Settings.Default` instance once to the DataContext of the StackPanel parent of the CheckBoxes:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=(p:Settings.Default)}">

    <CheckBox Content="Quick process" IsChecked="{Binding Pref_QuickProcess}"/>

    <CheckBox Content="Upload to Youtube">
        <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Pref_UploadToYoutube}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Pref_QuickProcess}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </CheckBox.Style>
    </CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for taking your time to help me out! I just didn't know what "stuff" I needed to use (DataTriggers) to accomplish what I wanted.